# How to get username after successful kerberos authentication using NGINX?

Tags: nginx, kerberos, identity

I have followed this tutorial (https://techexpert.tips/nginx/nginx-kerberos-authentication/) to creates a "special page" /test on my NGINX server that requires successful Kerberos authentication to access it.  So this much works.  The problem is, I want the application to know who actually just successfully authenticated to the site so I can show them their specific information.  So, for example, instead of popping up a page that says this to everyone:
Nginx authentication test
I want to have a page that will add the authenticated Kerberos username to the output or issue a cookie with the authenticated username in it.  This needs to support multiple, simultaneous users accessing the website so each will have access to their own information.

I should add that when I tailf the /var/log/nginx/access.log, I see a line that gets spit out with two dashes and what appears to be browser information from the browser accessing the site.  Then after successful Kerberos authentication, another line gets spit out to that log that has what appears to be the username filled in for the second dash.  So it seems like this information is available somewhere in nginx if I could only get access to it.  I don't really want to grab it from the access.log file. ;-)

Comment: Hmm, I just looked through the tutorial, and it seems it doesn't really make use of Kerberos - it uses _password_ authentication, and Nginx merely checks that password through Kerberos, but there is no actual SSO or Kerberos ticket exchange being done. (I was actually expecting the Nginx SPNEGO module to be used, which implements HTTP "Negotiate" authentication that's usually used in AD environments.) Still, that does not change the answer.

Comment: `request.environ["REMOTE_USER"]`
was not defined, and my guess is that's because we're not using NGINX SPNEGO.  However, I believe they have your header method working.  We'll see.

Comment: As long as you're using Nginx-level auth, then it would be set _regardless_ of the specific mechanism (i.e. it's equally valid for PAM or htaccess auth as it is for SPNEGO), but based on what you're saying, I'm assuming the problem is that Nginx talks to the webapp via HTTP proxying (which doesn't have a way to _pass_ "trusted" environment separately from untrusted headers) instead of uWSGI (which does). In that case, yes, a custom header will be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Nginx auth modules (whether Basic, or PAM, or SPNEGO for Kerberos) behave the same way – Nginx puts the username in `$remote_user` when processing nginx.conf, which then uses 'fastcgi_param' or 'uwsgi_param' to propagate it to the `REMOTE_USER` FCGI or WSGI variable.

So if you're using PHP via FastCGI, I'd expect to find it in `$_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]`, while Python using Flask would have `request.environ["REMOTE_USER"]`, and so on.

On the other hand, if Nginx talks to the webapp via HTTP (using 'proxy_pass'), you should be able to use 'proxy_set_header' to send $remote_user through (for example) X-Remote-User or another custom HTTP header – although you'd better make *very* sure that nobody but Nginx is allowed to talk to the webapp backend, otherwise they could spoof the header and walk right in.

Comment: Thanks, I'll relay this to the developers and see if they can make sense of it.  They are using Flask, so I'd expect request.environ["REMOTE_USER"] to do the trick.  I'll report back what I hope will be a success.

Comment: The custom HTTP header route was successful for or needs.  Thanks!